# How to make an abbreviation for line of code?

Tags: python

I want to put a pause in between almost every print statement, but I don't want to manually put

```
time.sleep(3)
```

in between each print.

```
import random

import time

print ("Hello")
time.sleep(3)
print ("What is your name?")
username = input("Name: ")
print ("Hello " + username)
time.sleep(3)
print("What brings you here?")
```

is there a way I can shorten it to a single word to put in between each thing?

Comment: You could write a function, then call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function...

```
def print_and_sleep(message1, message2, delay):
    print(message1)
    time.sleep(delay)
    print(message2)
```